# I need to add listeners to the checkboxes and changes in selection is shown in the textArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class JDorm implements ItemListener{

public static void main(String[] args){

    JCheckBox privateroom = new JCheckBox("Private Room",false);
    JCheckBox interweb = new JCheckBox("Internet Connection",false);
    JCheckBox cable = new JCheckBox("Cable TV connection",false);
    JCheckBox fridg = new JCheckBox("Refridgerator",false);
    JCheckBox microwave = new JCheckBox("Microwave",false);
    JCheckBox soon = new JCheckBox(",and so on",false);
    JLabel greet = new JLabel("Please choose ammenities");
    String sel = "Your selected options";

    JTextArea textBox = new JTextArea(sel,0,1);
    cable.addItemListener();

    JFrame dormFrame = new JFrame("Dorm Options");// creates frame with title
    final int WIDTH = 250;
    final int HEIGHT = 500;
    dormFrame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);// sets the size of frame in pixels
    dormFrame.setVisible(true);// note: default visibility is false
    dormFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    dormFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    dormFrame.add(greet);
    dormFrame.add(microwave);
    dormFrame.add(fridg);
    dormFrame.add(cable);
    dormFrame.add(interweb);
    dormFrame.add(privateroom);
    dormFrame.add(soon);
    dormFrame.add(textBox);
}
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
    Object source = event.getSource();
    int select = event.getStateChange();
}

}
```

This is what I have so far, I know I need listeners, and a message to appear in the box when selection is checked and unchecked. 
Do I need if statements for the changes?

Comment: Start by adding a listener to *one* checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

Create a generic listener that can be added to all the check boxes. Something like:

```
ItemListener listener = new ItemListener()
{
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)
    {
        JCheckBox checkBox = (JCheckBox)event.getSource();
        textBox.setText( checkBox.getText() );
    }
};
```

Then you add the listener to each check box:

```
privateRoom.addItemListener( listener );
interweb.addItemListener( listener );
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help? wish I knew how to thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have tried for one Checkbox and you can do others similarly

```
 final JCheckBox privateroom = new JCheckBox("Private Room",false);
```

Now add item listener to checkbox privateroom and also the actions which you would like to happen i.e.

```
 privateroom.addItemListener(new ItemListener()
    {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)
        {
            if (event.getItemSelectable() == privateroom)
                textBox.setText("Private Room");
        }
    });
```

The reason i have declared Checkbox privaterroom as final is because privaterroom is local and is being accessed from an inner class.

One more thing I don't know the way you have written your program is good or bad because I am also learning swing and am a newbie. But the way i write my program has the following structure

```
class MyClass extends JFrame implements LISTENER_NAME
{
    // Components declared here

    // constructor starts
    public MyClass()
    {
        //Componenets instantiated 
        // add listeners to appropriate components
        // setVisible(), setDefaultCloseOperation(),setSize() etc called

    }

    // listener interface methods here like

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie)
    {
        ................
    }

    // main method
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new MyClass();
    }
} // class over
```

This way I have never encountered the final keyword etc problems. I hope some expert will guide us.

Comment: I like your structure, it is easier to read and will try to make those good habits.